# Action of Galois group and direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, galois-extensions

Let $\Gamma$ be a degree $5$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $[\Gamma(\zeta_5): \Gamma] = 4 $ $(\zeta_5\, is\,\, 5^{th}\,\,\, root\,\, of\,\, unity)$ $G= Gal(\Gamma(\zeta_5)/ \Gamma) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ such that $Gal(\Gamma/\mathbb{Q}) = \langle\tau\rangle$ and $\tau^4 = 1$. we consider the action of  $G$ On  a $\mathbb{Z}_5[G]$-module denoted C.

I need to prove that $C \cong C^+\times C^-$ with $C^+ = \{\mathcal{A} \in C | \mathcal{A}^\tau = \mathcal{A}\}$ and $C^- = \{\mathcal{A} \in C | \mathcal{A}^\tau = \mathcal{A}^{-1}\}$.

I had found an element in $C^+$ ( is $\mathcal{A}^{1+\tau+\tau^2+\tau^3}$) but I don't find element in $C^-$, that verify the direct product of $C$

Comment: You are missing a lot of detail. Does it even matter that $G$ is a Galois group?? What's $C$?

Comment: I am sorry, I rectify the question

Comment: What is $\mathbb Z_5$? Integers mod $5$, $5$-adic integers, integers localized at $(5)$ or? And again, why does it matter that $G$ is a Galois group? That doesn't seem to be connected with the rest (which could, of course, still be true)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is the set of $5$-adic integers. Yes $G$ can be any group, but  in the problem I'm dealing with, $G$ is Galois group